# Index all files and folders under E:\data using batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I want to write a batch script which will make a CSV or JSON file containing all file and folders under E:\data. the informations I need to store are (file or folder name, size, type--file or folder, full location path).

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: note the low number of followers for each of the tags you are using (compared to Windows*, or Powershell). Best to add another, high-follower tag to your question. Most advanced users here, filter questions based on tags for their specialties. Good luck.

Comment: How do you define the size of a folder? Cumulative size of all files in the folder? Do you include content of subfolders?

Comment: @dbenham, no folder size should be 0 and file size should be the actual size.

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell can do that with ease. Have to add a little subexpression to give friendly terms about if it is a folder or file. Otherwise we could get rid of the entire `@{l=...}` bit and just use PSIsContainer and it would be True/False to state if it is a folder or not.

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Data -recurse | Select Name,Length,@{l='Type';e={if($_.PSIsContainer){'Folder'}else{'File'}}},FullName | Export-CSV C:\Path\To\Output.csv -NoType
```

Or, if you want to find out folder sizes of folders (including files in the folder) you could run this:

```
| Select Name,@{l='Size';e={if($_.psiscontainer){$_.getfilesysteminfos()|measure -Sum -Property length|select -expand sum}else{$_.length}}},@{l='Type';e={if($_.PSIsContainer){'Folder'}else{'File'}}},FullName | Export-CSV C:\Path\To\Output.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really a great help. a batch file would be better as I don't know powershell. However, if there is no other way, I have to learn it. :)

Comment: I know it's daunting, but if you like batch files it's worth the effort to learn PowerShell. It accepts a lot of very similar commands as aliases to the native PowerShell commands, so they tried to make the migration as easy as possible. Give it a try, I bet you'll like it.